# change environment during database update

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i am trying to update my database but `dotnet ef database update` uses wrong `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`
In log I see this `Using environment 'Development' instead of`Local`

this is my command :

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project ../API --configuration Local --verbose

"Local": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Local"
      }
    },
```

I also tried to use `--environment Local` but `environment` isn't defined as option even if https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7353 states otherwise

Comment: Run `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Local"` before `Update-Database`

Comment: You also added answer, I'm bit late

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to run this command before the database update:

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Local"
```